# Jquery mobile swiping does not work when <DIV> Id is numeric

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to change my DIV contents on swipe using Jquery mobile.

```html
<div id = 100>
   <div id  = 101 data-role="page"> ....Content 1....</div>
   <div id  = 101 data-role="page"> ....Content 2....</div>
   <div id  = 101 data-role="page"> ....Content 3....</div>
</div>
```

this works fine.
But my problem is I am giving  as numeric e.g 101, which is a must requirement for me.
Swiping does not work when DIV Id is numeric. It works with alpha or alphanumeric values.

Can anyone help me out..

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise against using numeric values for IDs of HTML elements. This can lead to a lot of unintended behavior.

My advise would be to call your div's id something like content_ and then removing the "content_" using jquery when you are loading the content.

Something like this:

```
var contentID = $('#content_101').attr('id').replace('content_','');




  <div id = "content_100">
       <div id  = "content_101" data-role="page"> ....Content 1....</div>
       <div id  = "content_102" data-role="page"> ....Content 2....</div>
       <div id  = "content_103" data-role="page"> ....Content 3....</div>
    </div>
```